# Html validation error for property attribute

Tags: html, http-headers

I am using few facebook social plugins and I am using the  meta header. When validating the page, the W3C validator is throwing the error -> "Error: there is no attribute "property".

I am using the XHTML Transitional doctype - `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Pls Suggest if I have to change the doctype to something else.

Comment: Post the offending code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761622/new-facebook-like-button-html-validation

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Facebook's plugins use [Open Graph](http://opengraphprotocol.org/), which is built on RDFa. It's RDFa that adds the `property` attribute to elements. Without this addition, plain HTML has no such attribute. (If you ask me, it's a strange design to add a new attribute without namespacing it, and to re-use half of a `<meta>` tag. But no-one did.)

To validate XHTML-with-RDFa, you'll need the DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

This means you will have to be writing valid XHTML 1.1. [More](http://rdfa.info/wiki/How-to-validate)

Comment: You are a genius indeed! My full header now looks like this (sorry, no markup).

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-2.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="XHTML+RDFa 1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
                        http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml-rdfa-2.xsd"
    lang="de"
    xml:lang="de"
    dir="ltr"
    xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
    >`

Comment: Ugh! Facebook must have had a very junior programming team! They openly state that "Developer simplicity is a key goal of the Open Graph protocol" adding a link to a slideshow (http://www.scribd.com/doc/30715288/The-Open-Graph-Protocol-Design-Decisions) in which it says that reusing the <link rel="canonical" ... is too complex ??? Too comlex!!! Reusing the normal name and title tags is probably also too complex? But mandating a specific XHTML+RDFa schema is developer simplicity? Oh well...

Comment: @StefanHoth did you manage to validate with that code? When I run it through W3C's validator I get:

**Error: value of fixed attribute "version" not equal to default**

Comment: @StevenGarcia Yes. Checkout my website to see it in action http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=stefanhoth.de&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks for following up on this - I will take a closer look at it

Comment: Your link to rdfa.org is dead, maybe the [spec at w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/) will suffice?

Answer (score 5):

In order for a document to claim that it is a conforming HTML+RDFa document, it must provide the facilities described as mandatory in this section. The document conformance criteria are listed below, of which only a subset are mandatory:

1. All document conformance requirements stated as mandatory in the HTML5 specification must be met.
2. There should be a `version` attribute on the `html` element. The value of the version attribute should be `HTML+RDFa 1.0` if the document is a non-XML mode document, or `XHTML+RDFa 1.0` if the document is a XML mode document.
3. There may be a link element contained in the head element that contains profile for the the `rel` attribute and http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab for the `href` attribute.

Example:

```
<html version="HTML+RDFa 1.1" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Example Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Moved to <a href="http://example.org/">example.org</a>.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

As [Open Graph](http://ogp.me) suggests, if you're using HTML5, you're better off just using a prefix attribute like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>
    <title>HTML5 site</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can leave the doctype as is and it will [validate](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

This approach has also been [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235687) by an Open Graph developer.