# there is no attribute "property" in facebook meta tag in validation w3c

Tags: facebook, validation, admin, meta-tags

can we use the `meta name="fb:admins"`
instead of
`meta property="fb:admins"`
for w3c validation ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761622/new-facebook-like-button-html-validation

Answer (score 8):

I'm answering this even though this is an old question since I think it's of value for whoever wants info on this in the future. Evan's probably right when he says it won't pass validation, but I think the answer is that you want to keep the `property=""` attribute. Taking from an [old Facebook developer forum post concerning this question exactly](https://web.archive.org/web/20120312120433/http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=58384) it turns out your document should be an XHTML + RDFa document. This will validate in W3C, thanks to the `DOCTYPE` declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0"
    xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
    xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Virtual Library</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="My Website"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Moved to <a href="http://example.org/">example.org</a>.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can find out more in in the [W3C spec for RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/#docconf), and in [this specific example of `<meta property=""/>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/#sec_2.2.).

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll just get this:

```
Line 1, Column 123: Bad value fb:app_id for attribute name on element meta: Keyword fb:app_id is not registered.
…="fb:app_id" content="176557225718913"><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="descr…
Syntax of metadata name:
A metadata name listed in the HTML specification or listed in the WHATWG wiki. You can register metadata names on the WHATWG wiki yourself.
```