# Meaning of property attribute in html

Tags: html

I just saw on one of the sites there is property attribute defined with some tags.
For example:-

```
<span property="amount">100</span>
```

I searched on net but there was no property attribute as such on w3schools atleast.
Can somebody please tell me what is it's role.

I am trying to run a simple html code but i don't understand its importance.

Can somebody please explain?

Comment: It does serve as a warning not to use W3Schools as a reference. It isn't as if it was posted as an answer.

Comment: @Quentin blunderboy is not using w3schols as a reference. And the w3fools page has big glaring errors itself.

Comment: @MrLister — "I searched on net but there was no property attribute as such on w3schools atleast"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`property` is an RDFa attribute. What you are seeing is probably related to that.

See http://www.w3.org/2010/02/rdfa/sources/rdfa-lite/  Section 2.1 vocab, typeof, and property

Comment: Got your point Alohci, Actually all those sites which use property attribute include namespace as 
<!--[if lt IE 7]> 
<html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en" version="HTML+RDFa 1.1"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
That's why their property attribute works..Thanks a lot    
<html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en" version="HTML+RDFa 1.1"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    
<html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en" version="HTML+RDFa 1.1"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    
<html class="no-js ie9" lang="en" version="HTML+RDFa 1.1"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->

Answer (score 1):

It is non-standard, invalid code.

If it has a role, it will be specific to the site it appears on (probably for the benefit of that site's JavaScript).

If it was HTML5 then it would be [`data-property`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) and not `property`.

Comment: But everybody also uses property attribute in their meta tags also. So if it is invalid code then it should show some error in browser console..??

Comment: Who is this "everybody" of which you speak? I don't think I've ever seen a property attribute on a meta tag.

Comment: Browsers do not report validity errors, they attempt to silently recover from the. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: `span` element only supports `class`,`dir`,`id`,`lang`,`style`,`title` and `xml:lang` as you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp). There is no `property` attribute, even in meta (ok, [there is something for Facebook graph api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166820/there-is-no-attribute-property-in-facebook-meta-tag-in-validation-w3c) but still this is not basic html).

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference, they are dreadful.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a standard attribute.
It's probably being used by custom code in that site.

It would be more correct to use a `data-*` attribute for such things.