# Css Validation Problem with facebook login button

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I hve used one facebook login button

in my site but it give 4 W3c error in http://validator.w3.org

1. there is no attribute "AUTOLOGOUTLINK"
2. there is no attribute "SIZE"
3. there is no attribute "PERMS"
4. element "FB:LOGIN-BUTTON" undefined

So, how can made a error free page with this button

my site is http://www.dialindia.com

Comment: Very related: [New Facebook like button HTML validation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2761622)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly this shouldn't be an issue tbh...

However if it bothers you, you can use jQuery to embed the FB login code once the DOM is ready so that it isn't sent as a part of the markup to the validator

Try something like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var fbCode = "Your facebook code goes here";
     $("#forgot").prepend(fbCode);
});
```