# Integrating facebook Channelurl into Javascript which enables xhtml validation

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I use a script I got from the thread below, and adapted slightly
[New Facebook like button HTML validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761622/new-facebook-like-button-html-validation)

however the channelurl doesn't work(lots of fd_fragment and multiple visits 10s apart) and I am not 100% convinced about the provenance or the effectiveness of the code, though it does leave me with valid xhtml,

I have tested the like function and it works for me, but I keep seeing "like" operations in my analytics that don't translate into visible "likes" from visitors

furthermore, I find no ref to "fbcont" in facebook literature

Sadly, javascript/ajax is not yet comfortable for me so i'm fumbling a bit here

Can anyone enlighten me about whats wrong with the code

Thanks

My Code:

```
<div id="FbCont">

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript">   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
var fb = document.createElement('fb:like');
fb.setAttribute("href","http://www.mydomainname.com");
fb.setAttribute("send","true");
fb.setAttribute("action","like");
fb.setAttribute("layout","button_count");
fb.setAttribute("show_faces","true");
fb.setAttribute("width","100");
fb.setAttribute("font","");
fb.setAttribute("channelUrl","http://www.mydomainname.com/channel.html");
document.getElementById("FbCont").appendChild(fb);
//--><!]]>
</script>

</div>
```