# Integrating facebook Channelurl into Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I use a following script which got from below thread, and i adapted it slightly.

[New Facebook like button HTML validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761622/new-facebook-like-button-html-validation)

However the channelurl doesn't work(lots of fd_fragment and multiple visits 10s apart) and I am not 100% convinced about the provenance or the effectiveness of the code, though it does leave me with valid xhtml,

I have tested the like function and it works for me, but I keep seeing "like" operations in my analytics that don't translate into visible "likes" from visitors

furthermore, I find no reference to "fbcont" in Facebook literature

Sadly, javascript/ajax is not yet comfortable for me so i'm fumbling a bit here.

Can anyone enlighten me about whats wrong with the code.

Thanks

My Code:

```
<div id="FbCont">

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript">   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
var fb = document.createElement('fb:like');
fb.setAttribute("href","http://www.mydomainname.com");
fb.setAttribute("send","true");
fb.setAttribute("action","like");
fb.setAttribute("layout","button_count");
fb.setAttribute("show_faces","true");
fb.setAttribute("width","100");
fb.setAttribute("font","");
fb.setAttribute("channelUrl","http://www.mydomainname.com/channel.html");
document.getElementById("FbCont").appendChild(fb);
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

Comment: 1. [so] is't a forum. 2. You don't need to ask same question twice just because you tagged it differently...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrating facebook Channelurl into Javascript which enables xhtml validation](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8898834/integrating-facebook-channelurl-into-javascript-which-enables-xhtml-validation)

Comment: @ifaour, It's almost char-to-char identical clone of this question, so it's not only possible it is duplicate. ;)

Comment: @JuicyScripter, hopefully "privileged" users will vote to close it as duplicate! It's really a shame that facebook.stackoverflow.com community is not even close to stackoverflow.com's!

Comment: @ifaour, it's actually the same community `facebook.stackoverflow.com` is just displaying Facebook related tags and users share reputation with [so] (it's not separate [se] site

Comment: @JuicyScripter, I'm *obviously* aware of this. BUT most of `facebook.stackoverflow.com` community do not necessarily participate in other parts of `stackoverflow.com` and I'm noticing that most of `stackoverflow.com` *power/privileged* users do not monitor `facebook` tag related questions as with other tags.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6914/discussion-between-ifaour-and-juicy-scripter)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the real like plugin.  Please follow the examples here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/