# Opengraph W3C valid?

Tags: html, w3c, facebook-opengraph

I would like to know if the opengraph markup is W3C valid,
I'm getting the following error when I try to validate it:

```
Line 14, Column 17: there is no attribute "PROPERTY"
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="sitename">
```

In case it's not valid, will it impact my pagerank and other search engines algo?

Is it possible to cloak those properties?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not valid in the normal HTML doctypes, but there is a doctype you can use to validate XHTML documents including Open Graph:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

See this question: [Html validation error for property attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704942/html-validation-error-for-property-attribute)

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't. That is why the validator reports an error.

Answer (score 2):

<html version="HTML+RDFa 1.1" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Example Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Moved to <a href="http://example.org/">example.org</a>.</p>
  </body>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

With this seems to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
```

Answer (score 1):

With this you are solving the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html vocab="http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1">
```

With this you can use lines in your html like this:

```
<meta property="og:title dc:title" content="m.clinic.pt - Está em boas mãos!">
```

or from other vocabularies listed (http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1) like this one:

```
cat:        http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#
qb:         http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#
grddl:      http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#
ma:         http://www.w3.org/ns/ma-ont#
owl:        http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#
rdf:        http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
rdfa:       http://www.w3.org/ns/rdfa#
rdfs:       http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
rif:        http://www.w3.org/2007/rif#
rr:         http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#
skos:       http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#
skosxl:     http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#
wdr:        http://www.w3.org/2007/05/powder#
void:       http://rdfs.org/ns/void#
wdrs:       http://www.w3.org/2007/05/powder-s#
xhv:        http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#
xml:        http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace
xsd:        http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#
prov:       http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#
sd:         http://www.w3.org/ns/sparql-service-description#
org:        http://www.w3.org/ns/org#
gldp:       http://www.w3.org/ns/people#
cnt:        http://www.w3.org/2008/content#
dcat:       http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#
earl:       http://www.w3.org/ns/earl#
ht:         http://www.w3.org/2006/http#
ptr:        http://www.w3.org/2009/pointers#
cc:         http://creativecommons.org/ns#
ctag:       http://commontag.org/ns#
dc:         http://purl.org/dc/terms/
dc11:       http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/
dcterms:    http://purl.org/dc/terms/
foaf:       http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/
gr:         http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#
ical:       http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/icaltzd#
og:         http://ogp.me/ns#
rev:        http://purl.org/stuff/rev#
sioc:       http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#
v:          http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#
vcard:      http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#
schema:     http://schema.org/
describedby:http://www.w3.org/2007/05/powder-s#describedby
license:    http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#license
role:       http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#role
```

You can validate it through http://validator.w3.org/ or http://html5.validator.nu/ very well.

So instead of this:

```
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Product">
   <img property="image" src="dell-30in-lcd.jpg" />
   <span property="name">Dell UltraSharp 30" LCD Monitor</span>
</div>
```

You can have this:

```
<!-- The schema: prefix is defined in the vocabulary http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1 -->
<div typeof="schema:Product">
   <img property="schema:image" src="dell-30in-lcd.jpg" />
   <span property="schema:name">Dell UltraSharp 30" LCD Monitor</span>
</div>
```

Some resources http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-primer/ http://manu.sporny.org/2012/mythical-differences/ http://rdfa.info/