# Is there any way to validate the Open Graph protocol meta tags for Facebook integration?

Tags: facebook, validation, protocols, facebook-opengraph

Is there any way to validate the Facebook Open Graph protocol meta tags in the head section of my website? Code below.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="my content" />
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mycompany.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mycompany.com/image.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="my site name" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="my_id" />
<meta property="og:description" content="my description" />
```

-edit- I mean validating the html. Sorry for the confusion! Right now my site isn't valid because of these tags.

Comment: OG tags will validate as HTML 5: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25575860/922522

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Facebook URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/)?

EDIT:
Ah, then refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959997/facebook-open-graph-meta-tags-valid-html) question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I meant validate the html. Right now, my site isn't valid because of these meta tags in the head.

Comment: @John: btw, can you give me [one](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.1) [big](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.1) [website](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F+&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.1) that validates? :-)

Comment: not including " [facebook](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=XHTML+1.0+Strict&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.1) "! :P

Answer (score 2):

...  open graph meta tags will only validate in HTML5....

http://validator.w3.org/