# Validator : og:image is not registered

Tags: html

any advice about that?

Bad value og:image for attribute name on element meta: Keyword og:image is not registered.

Comment: its not valid markup, see similar question/answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338499/html5-validator-failing-on-facebook-opengraph-xml-namespace-xmlnsog/8339047#8339047

Comment: any advice how to pass a share thumbnail? is here other any valid tags?

Comment: idk what you mean by pass a share thumbnail, sorry. other valid markup...in place of og? i'm assuming you're working with facebook, if so, then no, but remember, validation is a tool, use it, but don't live or die by it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to define the XML namespace `og`.

I would guess you need to change your `<html>` tag to read

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

so that the `og` prefix is declared. As [albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401672/albert) pointed out, you would either need to declare your document as XHTML as described at [#8338499: HTML5 validator failing on Facebook OpenGraph XML namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338499/html5-validator-failing-on-facebook-opengraph-xml-namespace-xmlnsog/8339047#8339047) or you could write them conditionally to the page, so that only the Facebook crawler sees them, as in [thejudge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049858/thejudge)'s answer to [#6501189: OpenGraph validation for HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501189/opengraph-validation-for-html5/8153178#8153178).