# Node lookupNamespaceURI support

Tags: dart, dart-html

The [Dart Node](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart%3ahtml.Node) implementation is missing [lookupNamespaceURI](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-lookupNamespaceURI).

Is support planned in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a reference but namespaces are outdated in HTML5 as far as I know.
Maybe this [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245807) has some information.

Comment: There are a still a handful of [supported namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/namespaces.html) in HTML5 like SVG. Dart has setAttributeNS, getNamespacedAttributes, etc. Would be nice to have lookupNamespaceURI too.

Comment: You can add a feature request at dartbug.com. I tried to use Facebook API on the client a while ago which makes heavy use of namespaces and got the answer that namspaces are outdated too. You could create a Dart-JS-interop wrapper to make that feature available in Dart.

Comment: I thin you should be able to get access to the JavaScript proxy by using `fromBrowserObject` (see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list?can=2&q=frombrowserobject&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+Area+Milestone+Owner+Summary+Modified&cells=tiles for examples) I haven't yet used this myself.

Comment: Submitted enhancement [18540](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18540) to dartbug.com.