# w3c validator shows error for facebook open graph

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, w3c-validation

I get 2 errors while validating my site in w3c validator.

Line 7, Column 47: Attribute xmlns:og not allowed here.
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" >

Line 7, Column 47: Attribute with the local name xmlns:fb is not serializable as XML 1.0.
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" >

I guess it is related with Facebook open graph. I'm running my site on wordpress and using All in one SEO pack with Social features enabled. When Social feature is disabled, my site validates perfectly with no errors. Is there any fix to this problem? 
This is how it looks on site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--// OPEN HTML //-->
<html lang="en-US"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" 
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" >

    <!--// OPEN HEAD //-->
    <head>

        <!--// SITE TITLE //-->
        <title>Aton usluge | Licencirana agencija za kreditno posredovanje</title>


        <!--// SITE META //-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

and so on..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xmlns` attribute is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-html-rdfa-20130822/#xmlns--prefixed-attributes) in HTML+RDFa 1.1.

You should use the `prefix` attribute instead:

```html
<html 
  prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# 
          fb: http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

resp. if you want to keep the `xmlns` for XHTML5:

```html
<html 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# 
          fb: http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: I'll try that, as soon as I figure out how to implement that since All in one SEO inserts that attribute automaticaly. Guess I should edit plugin files to get it done right. Thanks