# Open Graph protocol and validating html 5

Tags: html, validation

I have spent ages looking for a way to validate html 5 with the OGP meta tags with no luck - there seems not to be an answer as yet. So whilst I'm banging my head against a wall, can anyone help with, what is worth more, validating or adding the meta tags for OGP? Thanks. Of corse if anyone does know of a way to validate html5 with the tags, please say.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opengraph validation for HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501189/opengraph-validation-for-html5)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and now I'm using user agent detector.

There's an example here: [Opengraph validation for HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9238503/893111)