# Magento W3C and ADDTHIS and OGP tags (generate errors)

Tags: magento, w3c-validation

any advice on how to fix all the ADDTHIS and OGP tag faults on:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://shirtsofholland.com

What can we do/change to make the page loose those errors? Doctype?

I changed header to (based on information below and other links):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" 
xmlns:addthis="http://www.addthis.com/help/api-spec"
xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

Comment: You cannot validate this as XHTML, because the moment you add other namespaces to your document, it is no longer XHTML alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixable by adding the DTD schemas to the html tag in xhtml.

```
<html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:addthis="http://www.addthis.com/help/api-spec"
xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

Templates to change this in Magento are in `[magento]/app/design/frontend/default/[your theme]/templates/page[s]/` out the top of my head. They're usually defined in the basic html for the 1 column, 2 column and 3 column layouts.

I would like to note that Magento is a little behind on standards here, validating content isn't the most important thing for SEO reasons, and trying to beat Magento templates into shape is tedious and a lot of work to do properly. Try to fix the fixable, but definitly not everything.

**Other things that are wrong with this specific layout:**

You are using `data-*` attributes, which only became valid in html 5, as such you should use the html5 doctype `<!doctype html>` if you want to use them.

You are using attributes which aren't allowed in xhtml, like frameborder on iframes and height/width attributes on tables.

Values behind the hash (#) in an url need to be urlencoded/escaped, so an ampersand will be`%26` instead. Else they will throw an error in the validator.

**TinyMCE problems:**

The other errors you're experiencing have to do with the points I outlined above or how tinyMCE works (the text editor on the backend of Magento).

TinyMCE tries to wrap a paragraph element arround almost everything, this is mostly because the contenteditable attribute doesn't work in some browsers if there isn't any context for the browser.

The problems with tinymce are slightly deeper rooted problems and can only be fixed by overriding the default tinymce config in Magento and making your own implementation using the steps in the following tutorial:

http://www.gethifi.com/blog/how-to-produce-xhtml-10-strict-markup-with-tinymce

**More info on the Addthis validation:**

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api-#valid-xhtml

**More info for the opengraph validation:**

[Facebook open graph meta tags & valid html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959997/facebook-open-graph-meta-tags-valid-html)

Comment: Thx. And thats fast!!! But my OGP tags are in the header section. Is that a problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be if you use the tags as specified by OGP. The schemas you add to the html attribute merely add allowed tags and attributes in specific places of your document, this should include meta tags included in the header.

Comment: @snh_nl edited answer for the remaining problems you're experiencing.

Comment: Hi. Still muddling with all this. What about the following? The porblem is that I just cannot ignore some of the content (thus have to use the ifram tag for example): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd"> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: I'm not sure I am following you. In any case please note that adding the schemas will not take away the `there is no attribute "addthis:title"` errors since the w3c validator doesn't take into account additional dtd's even though they're technically valid. So I would advice on focusing on the problems that do not have anything to do with attributes which may or may not be placed at certain points. Please note that google uses custom tags and attributes as well and is not likely to punish other sites for doing the same.

Comment: If you have a new question, or a question which is about one specific problem in your validation please make a new question after searchin for answers that may already exist.