# HTML validation errors using Facebook RDFa doctype & meta property

Tags: facebook, validation, facebook-opengraph

I followed this stack, [Html validation error for property attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704942/html-validation-error-for-property-attribute), and used the RDFa doctype to work with the Facebook Open Graph.

My question is, how can I get the HTML Validator to work with this line of code (required):

```
<map id="Map" name="Map">
```

Currently the validator fails because "`there is no attribute 'name'`".

Here's my [page](http://bit.ly/o5quLF) and [validator error](http://bit.ly/p0cxya).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ["name" attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/abstract_modules.html#s_nameidentmodule) in XHTML [has been deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/changes.html) in favor of the "id" attribute for the map tag.